# I am looking to create an Array from the Output of Counts conducted by my string

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my below JS code, Develop and Array of 
Count of each vowels
1) Count of A
2) Count of E
3) Count of I
4) Count of 0
5) Count of U

Upon reading a string the code, generates the number of times each vowel occurs.
But now I need to create an array that display, the Vowel occurring the most frequently

I know it is something to do with creating a variable for

var biggestSoFar etc... But how to piece it together I am having problems.

/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
function count_all() {
var str = document.getElementById('txtname').value;
var count9=0, totalvowels="";
var count2=0, totalconsonants="";
var count3=0, total_digits="";
var count4=0, totalA="";
var count5=0, totalE="";
var count6=0, totalI="";
var count7=0, totalO="";
var count8=0, totalU="";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
if (str.charAt(i).match(/[a-zA-Z]/) !== null) {
    if (str.charAt(i).match(/[aeiouAEIOU]/))
  {
totalvowels = totalvowels + str.charAt(i);
count9++;
}
if (str.charAt(i).match(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/))
{
 totalconsonants = totalconsonants + str.charAt(i);
 count2++;
 }
 if (str.charAt(i).match(/[aA]/))
 {
 totalA = totalA + str.charAt(i);
 count4++;
 }

 if (str.charAt(i).match(/[eE]/))
 {
 totalE = totalE + str.charAt(i);
 count5++;
  }

 if (str.charAt(i).match(/[iI]/))
 {
 totalI = totalI + str.charAt(i);
 count6++;
  }

 if (str.charAt(i).match(/[oO]/))
 {
 totalO = totalO + str.charAt(i);
 count7++;
  }

 if (str.charAt(i).match(/[uU]/))
 {
 totalU = totalU + str.charAt(i);
 count8++;
 }

 }

 function retnum(str1) { 
 var num = str1.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
 return num; 
 }
 function count_digits(str2) {
  var num2 = str2.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
  return num2;
  }

  }
  document.getElementById('TotalU').value = count8;
  document.getElementById('TotalO').value = count7;
  document.getElementById('TotalI').value = count6;
  document.getElementById('TotalE').value = count5;
  document.getElementById('TotalA').value = count4;
  document.getElementById('consonant_counter').value = count2;
  document.getElementById('total_consonants').value = totalconsonants;
  document.getElementById('vowels').value = totalvowels;
  document.getElementById('vocount').value = count9;
  document.getElementById('digits1').value = count_digits(str);
  document.getElementById('digits2').value = retnum(str);
  }

  function clear_all()
   {
   document.getElementById('TotalU').value = "";
   document.getElementById('TotalO').value = "";
   document.getElementById('TotalI').value = "";
   document.getElementById('TotalE').value = "";
   document.getElementById('TotalA').value = "";
   document.getElementById('consonant_counts').value ="";
   document.getElementById('total_consonants').value ="";
   document.getElementById('vowels').value = "";
   document.getElementById('vcount').value = "";
   document.getElementById('digits1').value ="";
   document.getElementById('digits2').value ="";
   document.getElementById('txtname').value ="";
   document.getElementById('txtname').focus();
    }
```

Comment: why not use an object for counting with a single letter as key?

Comment: Hello there, Yes I was going to do that next, but I understood the logic on this version a lot easier, but I know there's ways of simplifying the actual structure itself.

Comment: How would you go about it

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this? You supply the `string` and it will return an `object` with a count for each vowel?

```
function countVowels(str) {

    var result = {};
    result.a = 0;
    result.e = 0;
    result.i = 0;
    result.o = 0;
    result.u = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        switch(str[i].toLowerCase()) {
            case "a":
                result.a = result.a + 1;
                break;
            case "e":
                result.e = result.e + 1;
                break;
            case "i":
                result.i = result.i + 1;
                break;
            case "o":
                result.o = result.o + 1;
                break;
            case "u":
                result.u = result.u + 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

When you get the result `object` back you can then do your checks to see which is the most occurring.

Comment: Thank you, So you are saying the Way I have it with separate Vars is not really correct

Comment: It's unnecessary really, you are creating 15+ variables when you can return one object. When you get the object back you can do simple comparisons to see which number is largest etc.

Comment: "document.getElementById('TotalU').value = result.u;"     Is that how I call it in the HTML file

Comment: And in the format I have it with 15+ variables... How would I create a variable to find the maximum of those... is it   // var Array=[count4,count5,count6,count7,count8];//

Comment: `var max = Object.keys(result).reduce(function(a, b){ return result[a] > result[b] ? a : b });`
Something like this may be what you need.

Comment: Hey there, it doesn't seem to be computing

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this could be like

```js
var str = "When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array. If separator is not found or is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the entire string. If separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of characters. If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability.",
 vowels = {"a":0,"e":0,"i":0,"o":0,"u":0},
     ok = Object.keys(vowels);
 maxvow = "";
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++ ){
  var chr = str[i].toLowerCase();
  chr in vowels && ++vowels[chr]; // or ok.includes(chr) && ++vowels[chr];
}
maxvow = ok.reduce((p,k) => vowels[k] > p[0] ? [vowels[k],k] : p,[0,""])[1];
console.log(vowels);
console.log(maxvow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and use an object for counting the vowels and other letters.

```js
var count = { a: 0, e: 0, i: 0, o: 0, u: 0, other: 0 },
    test = 'Es war einmal ein schwarzes Kaninchen';

test.toLowerCase().split(/(?=[a-z])/).forEach(function (c, i) {
    if (c[0] in count) {
        count[c[0]]++;
    } else {
        count.other++;
    }
});

console.log(count);
```